# Запятая в сложном предложении, в котором два глагола в разных наклонениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

Нужна ли запятая после слова **попристальней** в данном предложении?

> Вглядитесь в неё попристальней(,) и вы увидите лицо живописца, его привязанности.

Answer (score 4):

*Вглядитесь в неё попристальней, и вы увидите лицо живописца, его привязанности.*

Запятая ставится в сложносочиненном предложении по общим правилам.

В качестве исключения запятая может, к примеру,  не ставиться, если предложения в составе СПП являются односоставными и однородными, в этом случае они как бы приравниваются к однородным членам.

Например: *Запишите предложение и подчеркните главные члены*. Здесь однородные односоставные (побудительные) предложения, выраженные глаголами в одинаковой форме.

В приведенном примере мы имеем односоставное и двусоставное предложения.

Answer (score 3):

**Вглядитесь в неё попристальней, и вы увидите лицо живописца, его привязанности.**

Если в предложении глаголы стоят в **одной форме** **и** относятся к **одному субъекту**, то такое предложение считается простым. В вашем предложении глаголы имеют разное наклонение, поэтому предложение является сложным (сложносочиненным).

§ 30 [Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133)

> Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного (Газ.) —
>   сложносочиненное предложение (**глагольные формы разных наклонений не
>   выступают в роли однородных членов простого предложения**).